# Creating application using rails 2.3.5 and cassandra database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra

Pls guide me how to create rails application using rails 2.3.5 and cassandra database as rails 2.3.5 supports mysql, sqllite etc.

I typed in the command prompt like this

$ rails -d cassandra myapp

Databases supported for preconfiguration are: mysql, oracle, postgresql, sqlite2, sqlite3, frontbase, ibm_db

So pls help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra isn't supported by Rails. It is not actually a relational database and doesn't quite fit into the **Active Record** pattern used by Rails models.

I am sure there are client libraries you can use in the Ruby/Rails space:

- [Is Cassandra production ready for Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382436/is-cassandra-production-ready-for-ruby-on-rails)
- http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/cassandra-and-ruby-a-love-affair/