# List of supported databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a list of supported databases for RoR? I'm looking for MongoDB support but couldn't find anything official.

I'm a python/djangoist and have no clue for what keyword I should search in the RoR world. :(

All official I could find was that [small list](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) saying:

*Migrations are currently supported in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, SQL Server, Sybase, and Oracle (all supported databases except DB2).*

Are these all? Or is there maybe an app/plugin/whatever-its-called for RoR I could use?

Comment: I recommend having a look at [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html) and this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Question:

You are looking for supported databases officially covered by activerecord, the ORM default implementation in ruby on rails.

These are the supported connection adapters out of the box without gem enhancements.

Only these databases:
**MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite**

Source Code:
https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters

Second Question:

Mongo-Mapper is the gem that should be used to integrate MongoDB into Ruby On Rails 3.

Ruby Gem:
http://rubygems.org/gems/mongo_mapper

Instructions:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started

Answer (score 2):

As a start you may want to check out the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) in the category of [MongoDB clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/mongodb_clients).